# AES S_BOX Generator additive constants

Tags: aes, s-boxes

I try to generate other S_BOX for AES but I don't realize how to choose additive constants for S_BOX from decryption if for encryption it is `0x63` why is `0X05` used for decryption?

Comment: If you're looking to design an AES-like cipher, well, the fact that you need to ask this question would appear to indicate that you're seriously out of your depth...

Comment: it is 0x05 for decryption BECAUSE 0x63 is used for encryption, as that is the only value that satisfies the variable in the inverse equation